# Вложенный запрос с двумя полями к одной таблице

Tags: mysql

Можно ли 2 вложенных запроса к одной таблице, можно записать одним?

```
...     
(SELECT `name` FROM categories WHERE categories.id=notes.category_id) AS category,
(SELECT url FROM categories WHERE categories.id=notes.category_id) AS category_url,
...
```

Пробовал через запятую перечилсять их после SELECT и после  AS - не работает.

upd: вопрос собственно - как вложенный запрос к двум и более столбцам таблицы написать с одним SELECT?

Comment: а почему не одним запросом? у вас же выборка из одной таблицы по одному условию

Comment: @rdorn скорее всего имел ввиду "почему бы не сделать через join?" т.е. `SELECT... categories.name AS category, categories.url AS category_url... FROM notes... LEFT JOIN categories ON categories.id=notes.category_id...`

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, полный запрос. По указанному фрагменту сложно понять что вы хотите получить в результате.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вам нужно это, как сказал @ВОРОН

```
 SELECT notes.id, ..., categories.name AS category, categories.url AS category_url, ...
    FROM [notes]
    LEFT JOIN [categories] ON categories.id = notes.category_id;
```